# How to make fillRect() for a 2d canvas faster on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas, openlayers-3

I'm performing a spatial interpolation in a canvas —kriging with [kriging.js](https://oeo4b.github.io/)— on top of an OpenLayers (v4.6.4) map.

And I found out that `fillRect` is at least 20 times faster in Firefox than in Chrome. I'm wondering why because I would like to make that faster.

Here a snippet of the code I'm using.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.setAttribute("id", "krigingCanvas");
var canvas = document.getElementById("krigingCanvas");
var _2dContext = canvas.getContext("2d");

var width = 1287; // px
var height = 874; // px
var blocks = 10000; // number of squares we want
var step = Math.round( Math.sqrt(width*height / blocks) ); // width of squares, in px

var startTime = new Date(); // to measure performance

_2dContext.clip();
canvas.style.display = "block"; // make visible

var computations=0; // to count the iterations
for (var stepX = 0; stepX < width; stepX += step) { // steps on X axis
    for (var stepY = 0; stepY < height; stepY += step) { // steps on Y axis
        computations++;

        var predictedValue = kriging.predict(stepX, stepY, variogram); // quite fast

        _2dContext.fillStyle = "#" + rainbow.colourAt(Math.round(predictedValue)); // quite fast

        _2dContext.fillRect(stepX - step, stepY - step, stepX + step, stepY + step);
            // super fast on Firefox
            // very slow on Chrome
            // even slower if you keep the tab visible
    }
}

// to measure performance
var elapsedTimeMs = new Date() - startTime;
console.log(elapsedTimeMs + ' ms');
console.log( Math.round(1000* elapsedTimeMs/blocks)/1000 + ' ms/block');
console.log( Math.round(1000* elapsedTimeMs/computations)/1000 + ' ms/computations');
```

RESULTS:
- Firefox : 250–270 ms
- Chrome : 7k–50k ms (if I keep the tab visible)
- Chrome : 4k–6k ms (if I switch to another tab while it's running)

And I found out that the slow part is the line

```
_2dContext.fillRect(stepX - step, stepY - step, stepX + step, stepY + step);
```

because when it's commented out, the duration is always ~80ms, both in FF and Chrome.

I will need to increase the resolution (`var blocks`), these timings are just tests at low resolution to find the problem.

It's probably not a plugin because I tested in chrome private navigation as well

EDIT: Couldn't make a fiddle, so here is the whole live example I'm working on:  https://airq.surge.sh/ (click on "Kriging" after the markers are loaded)

Comment: Please explain before downvoting

Comment: It seems that clipping greatly impacts Chrome's performances. Can't you get rid of it? (Moreover it's unclear what it should be clipping here since you didn't defined a path, and that with the given code, it will just make your context undrawable anymore.

Comment: @Kaiido I removed it and I didn't really see any change (in performance and visually)